# adding youtube live streaming video to my site

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I want to add youtube live streaming video to my site this is the link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGYAnAoMbmA

and this is the code but it did not work:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGYAnAoMbmA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Embedding is disabled in the video's settings.

Comment: how can i enable it

Comment: You can't, only the person who's streaming it can...

Answer (score 0):

As the folks in the comments suggest, you should check to see if your YouTube video allows embedding.

Google has [this procedure](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en). Briefly speaking, first sign into YouTube, then [go to your Video Manager](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos). Click Edit beside the video you want to embed, then under the "advanced settings", find the "Distribution Options" and make sure the "Allow embedding" checkbox is checked; otherwise the embed will not work.

The good thing is that there appears to be no problem with your embed code, so it should only be a matter of making sure your video is even embeddable.